# Cannot post primitive types in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm posting very simple json data to a .net Core 2.0 API.

Why is it when I have a method like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNewToken([FromBody]string id)
```

Then id is null, but if I encapsulate that in a model:

```
public class RandomViewModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetNewToken([FromBody]RandomViewModel model)
```

Then my id is populated correctly?

Comment: How do you pass string id variable on request?

Comment: I'm just sending the data to the API using Postman for the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not get primitive types from your body directly like `([FromBody] string id)` if your route content type is `application/json` because mvc waits model to bind json body to model not primitive types.

There are some options to get primitive types from request body

1. Changing content type to plain/text.
2. Using `StreamReader` to get raw token string.
3. Using MVC `InputFormatter`

`StreamReader` Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNewToken()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {  
        var token = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); // returns raw data which is sent in body
    }
    // your code here
}
```

`InputFormatter` example: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers

Comment: Using Streamreader doesn't strike me as the best idea, as then my property isn't strongly typed.  Also my json data is being sent in the way you have shown

Comment: It should work with GetNewToken([FromBody]RandomViewModel model) if you send your post request with json data i have shown

Comment: It does work.  I explain that in my question.  My question was why the first method signature doesn't work

Comment: @RobbieMills I have updated my answer. You can not get primitive types from your body directly like ([FromBody] string id) if your route content type is application/json because mvc waits model to bind json body to model not primitive types.

Comment: Your link is now broken for InputFormatter

Answer (score 8):

You can in fact post a primitive type from request body, but you should not use the key/value, for example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LockUserByDate(Guid appUserId, [FromBody] string lockoutEnd)
```

Consider this action, when I test it in Postman if I use this for the body:

```
{
 "lockoutEnd": "2018-03-15 16:30:35.4766052"
}
```

Then it dosen't bind but If I use only the value in the body, model bindler bind the value:

```
"2018-06-15 16:30:35.4766052"
```

[image]

Comment: we can use [FromForm] instead of [FromBody] too

Comment: I am still getting null with this approach as well. not able to fetch primitive types still.

Comment: also getting null on primative types with this approach