# c# Send 3 parameter from angular to c#mvc and i get null on the server side

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, post

I'm trying to pass 3 parameters (2 types and one string),
but on the server side the parameters are null

this is my service

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json '
      })
};
let body = {
  auditId: auditId,
  rolId: this.permisoService.currentUserRolValue.rolId,
  valores: JSON.stringify(valores),
}
return this.http.post<any>(this._saveURL, body, httpOptions).pipe(
  map(res => { return res; }),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
}
```

and the service side

```
[HttpPost, Route("AuditMail/Save"), Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] int auditId, int rolId , String valores)
    {
        return Json(await _repository.Save(auditId, rolId, valores));
    }
```

i try to change the content-type to text/plain, remove [FromBody] with the same result,

I will appreciate any help thank you
[image: POST]

Comment: Are all arguments null??

Comment: @HadiSamadzad the two int (int auditId, int rolId) are 0 and the string yes it null

Answer (score 1):

See this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082613/12431728 which says:

> You can not get primitive types from your body directly like `[FromBody] string id` if your route content type is application/json because mvc waits model to bind json body to model not primitive types.

I would recommend creating a new class in your API project that holds these values:

```c#
public class AuditMailModel
{
    public int AuditId { get; set; }
    public int RolId { get; set; }
    public string Valores { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```c#
public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] AuditMailModel model)
{
    return Json(await _repository.Save(model.AuditId, model.RolId, model.Valores));
}
```